# Expected resource type of anim

Tags: android, android-animation

.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.in_animation, R.animator.out_animation)
the following throws "Expected respource type of anim"

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.in_animation, R.animator.out_animation)
            .replace(R.id.a_fragment, SingleAnswerFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

I did check this stack over flow thread [Android Studio's "expected resource of type" checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716385/android-studios-expected-resource-of-type-checks) and I did see where in this case I might use @Animator Res annotation, but i'm not sure how I would use that in the middle of my method chaining as shown above

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511350/5596604 Here I see a possible solution but have no idea what he means in his steps where he, (Imported the NineOldAndroids library into the support-v4 Library
Imported the support-v4-nineoldandroids library into my project.) The github link for that support library for NineOldAndroids, states in the configuration part " remove Google's support v4 library from your classpath."

Comment: OP I feel your pain on this, this is a very retarded error provided to us by Google.

Comment: It was working fine before I upgraded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are providing `R.animator` resources (`@AnimatorRes`) to the `setCustomAnimations()` method but it expects `R.anim` resource type (`@AnimRes`). If you switch to some animations which are referenced by `R.anim` it should compile and work.

> but i'm not sure how I would use that in the middle of my method chaining as shown above

I'm not sure what you mean by this. Maybe [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations) could shed some light on the matter. Also [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/package-summary.html) you can find a list of all the Android annotations with short descriptions.

Comment: sorry I meant in this line .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.in_animation, R.animator.out_animation) how would I use the @Animatorres to suppress the warning

Comment: You should use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html) resources. E.g. `.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)`. You wouldn't use the `@AnimatorRes` annotation to suppress the warning, the warning is there because you are using `R.animator` and not `R.anim`.

Comment: I switched my animations to a anim folder and now the app crashes when I click for animation, I'm getting this error, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator

Comment: You'll have to provide more information than that. Please edit your question and provide more code samples and the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setCustomAnimations with [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) only with android.app.Fragment. And with android.support.v4.app.Fragment you should use [TweenAnimation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are using fragment of class `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, but not `android.app.Fragment`. This class is not allowing property animation that you try to use.
If so, change your fragment to `android.app.Fragment` (change all other accordingly, for example `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`), this should help.